# Quartic Diophantine equation in three variables

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Is there a positive integer solution to the quartic Diophantine equation?
$$x^4-4x^2y^2+8y^4=z^2$$

Cf. Yiu,"Recreational Mathematics" Chap. 6.2 pp. 50/360

Sinha, T. N. Two simultaneous diophantine equations. Math. Student 33 (1965), 59-61

Comment: Checked for $z<1000$ without solutions.

Comment: Maybe, it helps that the left side is $$(x^2-2y^2)^2+(2y^2)^2$$ There is no solution for $1\le x,y\le 10^4$

Comment: Probably , the only solutions are possible when either $x$ or $y$ can be equal to $0.$

Comment: Probably not relevant , but $$a = p^2(4q^2 - p^2 )$$   $$ b = 4q^2(p^2-2q^2)$$ and $$c = p^4 - 4p^2q^2 + 8q^4$$ are Pythagorean triplets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is NO.

The quartic is birationally equivalent to the elliptic curve
\begin{equation*}
v^2=u(u^2+2u-1)
\end{equation*}
with
\begin{equation*}
\frac{x}{y}=\frac{v}{u}
\end{equation*}

Pari-GP gives the torsion subgroup of the curve as having only one finite point
$(0,0)$, whilst Denis Simon's $\mathbf{ellrank}$ code gives the rank as $0$.

Thus, the only rational point on the curve is $(0,0)$ which does not, clearly, give a solution.